# Syncing Plugins between two IntelliJ IDEs - Which one is the "primary" one all other IDEs having to sync against?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I have a hard time understand the plugin syncing for Jetbrains IntelliJ. At work I have some plugins and at home I have a different set. Always when I sync it's somehow activated/deactivating the ones from the other IDE.

I'd like to tell which one is the primary one and the others should just sync towards that one. Is that possible somehow? Otherwise I will always have to sync back and forth.

Comment: Do you use JetBrains Account to sync settings?

Comment: @y.bedrov Yes I do

Comment: You may try to disable sync on both machines, enable it on primary one, select "Keep and Sync local settings"  (it will store settings from primary machine), then enable on the other machine and select "Get settings from account".